# Iterating over an object's array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have a class called User which has an array of products(objects).

Somewhere else I have an array of users. The problem is that I want to have access to `products[0]` of `users[0]`.

```
$users[0] = new User("ion","ion123","seller",$productsUser0);   
//construct allProducts array
$allProdCounter = 0;
$usr = $users[0];
$prodArray = &$users[0]->productsArray;
print_r($prodArray);
```

When I run the code, there appears the following error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property User::$productsArray has no effect

What is the problem?

Comment: This isn't how you should use OOP. Passing object params by reference is bad practice!

Comment: you should not use the ampersand (`&`), or references, before knowing exactly what you're doing. First, php already passes all objects as references (sort of) so doing it is kind of redundant, second, it is not at all a proof that your script will run faster. http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier `PHP passes all objects as references`? Really?

Comment: @BenM did your purposefully left out the `(sort of)` part of my comment? anyway here's the link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php `As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.`

Comment: @BenM, see [how-php-manages-variables](http://webandphp.com/how-php-manages-variables) it includes an explanation of 'copy on write'.

Comment: @RyanVincent OK, fair point. Perhaps I was being somewhat of a pedant. Sorry, it was early :P